# I have about 10k lines of code in my main class, should I worry?

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

I am creating a Java Frame with the NetBeans designer. It is quite extensive, it's mostly about inserting and getting data from a DB.

The thing is my main class currently has 10663 lines (7000 are inserted by the designer, frame design - generated code). Will this cause any problems? I'm new to Java and have read that a class shouldn't have more than 20 methods / 500 lines of code. I have just around 15 methods but 10k lines of code, will this be a problem?

Can't split or rethink the code from an OOP perspective as it's not really a OOP problem, I just populate some tables (many tables) with data from a MySQL DB when some buttons are pressed / update the DB with data from numerous forms.

Edit:
I feel like I haven't given enough details so I'll add here everything there is to know. This is my college graduation paper basically, it will not be used or updated ever again after I get my grade and graduate. It is about creating a software product for a hotel's reception - everything from adding customers, checkins, managing basic/extra services offered to the client etc. When I started the project I had 0 Java knowledge, I have been learning along with it.
I have a Java file that does all DB related stuff such as adding/deleting/updating records etc.
I have a form file that contains the said problem - 11k lines of code. Here is what most of it looks like:

```
    private void cCautaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> result;
    ArrayList<String> attributes=new ArrayList();
    String where = "first_name LIKE '%" + cclientName.getText() + "%' OR last_name like '%" + cclientForename.getText() +"%'";
    attributes.add("id");
    attributes.add("first_name");
    attributes.add("last_name");
    attributes.add("address");
    attributes.add("number");
    attributes.add("town");
    attributes.add("county");
    attributes.add("notes");
    attributes.add("cnp");
    attributes.add("type");
    csearchedCustomersList.clear();

    try {
        result = DataBaseConnection.getTableContent("customers", attributes, where, null, null);
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) csearchTable.getModel();
        DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRender = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        centerRender.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
        csearchTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, centerRender);
        model.setRowCount(0);
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            errorMessage("error", "No client found with the specified name!", "Search Error");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            Customers cust = new Customers((String)(result.get(i).get(0)),
                (String)(result.get(i).get(1)),
                (String)(result.get(i).get(2)),
                (String)(result.get(i).get(3)),
                (String)(result.get(i).get(4)),
                (String)(result.get(i).get(5)),
                (String)(result.get(i).get(6)),
                (String)(result.get(i).get(7)),
                (String)(result.get(i).get(8)),
                (String)(result.get(i).get(9))
            );
            csearchedCustomersList.add(cust);
            model.addRow(result.get(i).toArray());
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    }
}
```

This for example is the code for a Search button that populates a table with customers that match the searched terms (name and forename).
So DataBaseConnection does all the DB work. Problem is now when I try to add anything - a new JPanel, change a button's icon.. basically add any new code I get an: Error: could not find or load main class Hotel.hotel. Not sure how should I approach this because, as I said, I'm fairly new to Java.

Comment: The frame should *not* be responsible for database management. So yes, this is an OOP problem. The frame should just raise events on button click that are dealt with by some other class.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Model - View - Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) paradigm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be worried. The problem is that your program lacks a reasonable structure. It's not just about OOP, code generation or large source files. You can get away with that just because the program is still relatively small and there's no actual need to consider maintainability.

Lack of a proper structure leads to unbearable complexity and cognitive load. Eventually adding new features to the application or changing any behavior will become very unpleasant, difficult or even impossible. It seems you are just about to hit that wall.

You could begin with separating all database related code from the user interface. The listener method you gave as an example shouldn't be handling connections and query strings and such. The functionality it really needs is getting certain customers from some repository. You need to think about layers and/or modules. Separating generated code from written would be wise too.

A simple [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)-structure could work for your application. [Here's](http://shulgadim.blogspot.fi/2012/01/model-view-controller-mvc-pattern_13.html) a simple example showing how it could be implemented with Swing.

Answer (score 3):

When the code is auto-generated by a tool, it's usually not a problem when it gets bloated, because it usually isn't supposed to be human-readable anyway.

It does, however, get problematic when you mix auto-generated code with your own. You usually can't re-generate the code without destroying your own work, tools which read the code get confused by your modifications and modifying machine-generated code is rarely a pleasureable experience.

When somehow possible you should avoid editing the auto-generated code and do any of your own programming in a different class.

You aren't telling us much about your program, so we can only guess what could be good ways to improve your class design. But when you have multiple tables, buttons and forms, it could make sense to create an individual class for each one.

Comment: I have updated my original post with a lot more info about my problem. I am not modifying any generated code, I am just adding functionality to buttons, checkboxes, lists etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes worry. Besides it pains when a .form file gets corrupted, there is more. Split and separate the views, JPanel forms. Data might be really data i.o. hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

I know that code from NetBeans designer... it gets quite messy very quickly. But as long as you only work on it with the designer you should be fine. 
Longer classes tend to become unmaintainable after some time. You should really put some of the code into separate classes.
Do you use an OR mapper for the database abstraction? If so you can create entityclasses per form which will greatly simplify your code